# mapping network drive through webpage

Tags: c#, network-drive

I have created a small webpage that runs on our local company intranet.  All it does is map a network drive using this code

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net.exe", "use H: "+DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
```

This works fine when I run the webpage locally.  But when I run it off of the webserver it won't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks, should I be doing this with javascript?

Answer (score 3):

This does not work on remote clients because the code *runs on the server*.  When you test locally, this code runs in your web server, which is on the same computer as the web client.

You cannot do this in the browser client.  All code that runs in the browser runs in a sandbox that just does not give this level of access to the host operating system.

When a user runs this remotely, you will find that they remap the H: drive on the *server*.  When the next user comes along, they *remap* H: on the *server*.

Answer (score 0):

Eric J's answer is completely correct.

Dirty suggestion - you could dynamically generate a batch file on the server containing the "net use" statement as in your question, allow the client to download it, and ask the user to run it?